# multiprocessing sum python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have the following code.

```
from itertools import repeat
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
import numpy as np

a=[1,2,3]
b=[2,3,4]

def multi_run_wrapper(args):
    return add(*args)
def add(x,y):
    return x+y


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool( os.cpu_count())
    results = pool.starmap(add,zip(a,b))
    print(sum(results))
```

the output would be `results= [3, 5, 7]`.  and  print out `15`.
So in this way, if I want to calculate sum of `results`, I need to save the whole list `results`.
Is there a way of using multiprocessing without saving the whole list? For example, sum the `results` while using mulprocessing. Because if my list `a` and `b` become super long, then the output `results` would take too much memory and it won't fit in my laptop.
In other words, my goal is to get `sum(results)` without saving the whole list but speed up the process at the same time.

Thank you

Comment: Feels like Map/Reduce (https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/mapreduce.html) would do what you want.  It's built for large data sets.

Comment: "Is this question fundamentally asking the same thing as that other question?" : NO. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408268/7317733 Please make sure before closing the question as duplicate.

Comment: @AvidJoe Yes, it is. The linked question is about an iterative starmap, or in other words a starmap "without saving the whole list". Whether the iterative starmap is used to sum or to display a progress is inconsequential. FWIW, a progress bar *does* an internal sum over the element count. Please make sure to provide a reason *why* a duplicate is not appropriate when challenging it.

Comment: @MisteMiyagi https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292372/7317733 . I am new here and do not know what to make of these posts but I feel this link explains what I want to say. I guess. So if the op just reads the linked question he is supposed to go to tqdm and understand this " a progress bar does an internal sum over the element count." to even begin to understand what's going on?

Comment: @AvidJoe They are supposed to see that the other question comes down to an iterative starmap, which is what they asked about. As a simile like in your second link, they asked "how to implement the ``*`` in ``2*13``" and the other question asked "how to implement the ``*`` in ``4.5*27.3``".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks for the comment. I think i understand now.

Comment: @Gina09 You can find the duplicate question in the header above this question. The header should also give you a link detailing why we do this and how you can challenge it if you disagree. The direct link to the appropriate help center page is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: @Gina09 The TLDR is that you can add the ``istarmap`` method as shown in the other question, then use ``results = pool.istarmap(add,zip(a,b))`` instead of ``results = pool.starmap(add,zip(a,b))``.

Comment: I don't get it why it can get sum(results) using your solution.

Comment: The goal is to get sum(results). and I didn't see an answer in the link.

Comment: @Gina09 Because the ``pool.istarmap`` (from the other question) is to ``pool.starmap`` what ``pool.imap`` is to ``pool.map``: it does the same operation as its regular variant, but instead of storing all results into a list it yields each result as soon as it becomes available. ``sum`` can work with both iterables (what ``imap``/``istarmap`` provides) and lists (what ``map``/``starmap`` provides).

Answer (score 1):

When processes are run in a self contained environment you will definitely have less things to worry about :) . If you need to do it, you could use the `Queue` object to modify a single variable this way to achieve Inter process communication.

```py
from itertools import repeat
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import os
import numpy as np

a=[1,2,3]
b=[2,3,4]

def multi_run_wrapper(args):
    return add(*args)
def add(queue,x,y):
    queue.put(queue.get(block=True)+x+y)  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue = Queue()
    queue.put(0)
    processes = []
        processes = [Process(target=add,args=(queue,x,y)) for x,y in zip(a,b)]
    for each in processes:
      each.start()
    for each in processes:
      each.join()
    print(queue.get(block=True)) # prints 15
    queue.close()
    queue.join_thread()
```

- If you want to do it with `Pool`

```py
from itertools import repeat
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue
import os
import numpy as np

a=[1,2,3]
b=[2,3,4]

def multi_run_wrapper(args):
    return add(*args)
def add(x,y):
    queue.put(queue.get(block=True)+x+y)   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue = Queue()
    queue.put(0)
    pool = Pool( os.cpu_count())
    pool.starmap(add,zip(a,b))
    print(queue.get(block=True))
    queue.close()
    queue.join_thread()
```

- Here you aren't storing the entire list of outputs from each process rather you are communicating to each process where to modify.
- came up with a quick solution, haven't tested it though.